blogger API updated div content with new post based on select box
I am using the below code. which gets the posts from my blog and displays the most recent in a div. The other div is a select drop down that when i change does update the values I require from the json file (i am using alert to test this) however it wont update the blog1 div with the new content from the corrosponding blog post. What am I missing?
<script>
    function getBlogidval(selectObject) {
        var value = selectObject.value;
        var upblog = document.getElementById("blog1");
        alert(value);
        upblog.innerHTML = "<h2>" + data.items[value].title + "</h2><br>"
    }

    function handleResponse(response) {
        document.getElementById("blog0").innerHTML = "<select id='Blogidval' onchange='getBlogidval(this)' width='100%' align='center'><option value='0'><h2>" +
            response.items[0].title + "</h2></option>" + "<option value='1'><h2>" + response.items[1].title + "</h2></option>" + "<option value='2'><h2>" +
            response.items[2].title + "</h2></option>" + "<option value='3'><h2>" + response.items[3].title + "</h2></option><select>";
        document.getElementById("blog1").innerHTML = "<h2>" + response.items[0].title + "</h2><br>" + "<p>" + response.items[0].content + "</p>";
    }
</script>
handleRepsonse calls the json from from the google API. same as below but with my api key and blog ID.
<script
    src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3213900/posts/8398240586497962757?callback=handleResponse&key=YOUR-API-KEY"></script>

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

You have the last select not closed

Thanks @Mehdi i've closed that off but still can not figure out why it wont refresh the div content to data from the API.

Can't really figure it out without the whole code but I think you should check the data object in data.items[value].title if properly fetched or is it response.items..
